# Can't connect to MySQL DB using node-mysql

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I'm learning Node.js, and I've decided to poke at node-mysql. I'm trying to insert some text, and its not working-when I query the relevant table, nothing is there. When I set a breakpoint and debug, the connection state says "disconnected." What am I doing wrong?

Node code:

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'XXXXX',
            password: 'YYYYY',
            database: 'chat'

        });

        connection.connect();


    var objToday = new Date(),
            weekday = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'),
            dayOfWeek = weekday[objToday.getDay()],
            domEnder = new Array( 'th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th' ),
            dayOfMonth = today + (objToday.getDate() < 10) ? '0' + objToday.getDate() + domEnder[objToday.getDate()] : objToday.getDate() + domEnder[parseFloat(("" + objToday.getDate(    )).substr(("" + objToday.getDate()).length - 1))],
            months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'),
            curMonth = months[objToday.getMonth()],
            curYear = objToday.getFullYear(),
            curHour = objToday.getHours() > 12 ? objToday.getHours() - 12 : (objToday.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + objToday.getHours() : objToday.getHours()),
            curMinute = objToday.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + objToday.getMinutes() : objToday.getMinutes(),
            curSeconds = objToday.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + objToday.getSeconds() : objToday.getSeconds(),
            curMeridiem = objToday.getHours() > 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
//var today = curHour + ":" + curMinute + "." + curSeconds + curMeridiem + " " + dayOfWeek + " " + curMonth + " " + dayOfMonth + ", " + curYear;
        var today = curYear+"-"+curMonth+"-"+dayOfMonth+" "+curHour+":"+curMinute+":"+curSeconds
        var post={time: today, message: msg.message};
        var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO messages SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
            // Neat!
            console.log(result);
        });
        //console.log(result);
        io.emit('chat message', msg);

    });
```

when i set a breakpoint right after connection.connect(), I look at connection in the watch window, and connection.state ="disconnected." I'm running WebStorm on a Mac.
 EDITED TO ADD: Rest of code

Comment: You are missing the closing `});` to your `socket.on(`. Was that a typo?

Comment: There's more to the socket, but I didn't think I'd need to show that code, since I noticed it wasn't connected even before it

Comment: Are you pointing to a local database? Or on a server?

Comment: Its just a local instance on my machine running localhost

Answer (score 1):

The actual connection to the database is made asynchronously, so it's not going to be connected *right after* `connection.connect();`. If you just call `connection.query(...);` it should implicitly connect and automatically execute the query upon connection.

Also on an unrelated note, you may wish to use a pool of database connections that you create before starting up your socket.io server instead of creating a new database connection on every single chat message event. This should help prevent someone from DoS'ing your database server (either intentionally or accidentally).